# Postgres permissions - schema not showing using \dt

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.3

I have no experience in postgres, and am trying to get a staging site correctly configured.

The database has a schema `data` in the database `drupal`. 
I imported the database from development using (as postgres user):

```
psql drupal <drupal.dump.sql
```

When I connect *as the `drupal` user*, and execute `\dt`, it only shows the regular tables and not the tables in the schema "data".

I see those "missing" tables when I execute `\dt *.*`

I am probably missing some permissions to be added to the drupal user. Any help greatly appreciated!

Postgres version: 9.3.17

Comment: I don't get the question do they show when you execute `\dt` or not you say both things.

Comment: When you run `\dt` and see the tables, are you connected as the `drupal` user still, or as a different user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the schema "data" in your `search_path` if you want the tables from that schema to show up in a `\dt` run with no arguments.  (If your import worked, then you already have permissions to the schema, unless you changed users)

Comment: I compared the search_path settings between development and staging, and saw that the settings were very different. Set the search path to match, and all is well now, thanks! 
On the postgres prompt: show search_path; set search_path public, data;

Comment: It's usually done the other way around (set search_path data, public) as it is often - but not always - more important to get information from your specific schema first than the public one.

Comment: In this particular case, the public one is more important than the specific one. I also realized, that I had to execute this, to make the change permanent: alter role drupal set search_path to public, data;